# Determine if a DataGrid has focus based on ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid and another plot view and they both can scroll horizontally since their data is correlated.  I implemented each to scroll on their own.  So I can scroll on the plot (old Winform, not WPF), and then the DataGrid ScrollIntoView gets called.  **OR** I can scroll the DataGrid, and I have an eventhandler for the ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged to move the plot horizontally.

However, I am running into a circle with them calling each other if I implement them both.  How do I determine which has focus, or create some sort of flags/state machine so that only one gets called at a time?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was using ScrollViewer controls to provide the scrolling functionality.

[Here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/07/exposing-and-binding-to-a-silverlight-scrollviewer%E2%80%99s-scrollbars/) is the link that helped me.

I used the provided attached property to bind the same property of the ViewModel to both ScrollViewer controls in two way mode.

Hope it helps.